# MYSQL query / dates older than 1 week ago (all datetimes in UTC)

Tags: mysql, datetime, utc

How do I query a mysql db to return all records with a datetime older than 1 week ago. Note that the datetime table stores everything in UTC, and I should be comparing it in that itself.

Just to be clear - I'm looking for a pure mysql query.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

If your table stores datetimes in different timezone than what `NOW()` returns, you can use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead to get the timestamp in UTC.

Answer (score 25):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),colname) > 7;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: this one is shorter, should i use this one?

Comment: Maybe this is shorter but how would it be able to use an index.

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT SUBDATE('2008-01-02', 7);
```

OR

```
SELECT SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 1 week);
```

Result:

2007-12-26