# PHP and mysql query after cutoff date based on mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I've mysql DB, which stores timestamp (date + hour).

I'd like to use this data to create cutoff points, like week ago, month ago etc...

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
u.user_id,
  ( SELECT sum(r.result_value)
    FROM logos_results r
    WHERE r.user_id = u.user_id
    AND r.result_date <= '$week' ) AS rsum,
u.user_name,
u.user_pic,
u.user_logos_level
FROM users u
ORDER BY rsum DESC
LIMIT 4");
```

My question is, how do I create week in php?
Should I remove timestamp and use something without hours? Will this exact time decrease speed of query considerably? `AND r.result_date <= '$week'` this is the important part, is syntax correct?

Comment: suggestion: upgrade to the latest PHP and use the datetime object. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you won't use mysql ability to convert weeks to date or to select intervals by week?

To me it seems better than implementing your week to date logic in php.

[Check this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600481/mysql-query-dates-older-than-1-week-ago-all-datetimes-in-utc)

```
SELECT sum(r.result_value)
    FROM logos_results r
    WHERE r.user_id = u.user_id
    AND r.result_date < NOW() - INTERVAL $num_of_weeks WEEK
```

Comment: Correct answer finally.  I wondered when / if someone would point out the obvious.  Anyone using PHP for calculating dates etc for limitations or selections from a database where its already storing an internal time stamp should be shot.  They waste many lines of code and loads of processing power when all db's have the facilities built in.

Comment: @Dave well not everyone knows what you know, and not all of us are developers... but simple code tinkerers who do personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use unix timestamps instead of your datetime values. Those contain number of seconds since Epoch (1.1.1970) and can be easily used in calculations.

Another approach could be to use datetime and either MySQL methods for date values:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

or calculate in PHP with DateTime Objects or strtotime()

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php
https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php

```
$nextweek = strtotime ( "+1 week")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$week = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 week")); // 1 week from now
$week = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("-1 week")); // 1 week ago

$month = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("-1 month")); // 1 month ago
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php