# How to offset query by date?

Tags: php

To prevent fraud im looking to offset earnings by 5 days. I pay my users for leads every Friday, basically what i want to do is have the query only to include amounts past last Sunday or past 5 days basically.

This is the query currently in my payments file.
`$reports = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rate) as total_earned FROM`reports`WHERE`status`= '2' AND`pid`= '".$row['id']."'");`

I've been reading around here and i got the idea to use `where date >= date('2015-12-25');`

i have the dates stored as `2015-07-17 01:45:46` so im trying to basically compare the current date.

I tried adding `WHERE date > ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - INTERVAL 2 DAY` which dont work.

Comment: @ciccio the answer is using NOW

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3600537/2433843 Also, I suggest you update your code and stop using the now [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: It is using NOW minus an INTERVAL.

Comment: Try `WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY`

Comment: that makes no results show mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rate) as total_earned FROM `reports` WHERE `status` = '2' AND `pid` = '".$row['id']."' AND date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)");