# How to compare records by date and return only those match the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains a list of `teams`, each `team` have a field called `update_at` that specify the `datetime` of the last update.

I need to check for each `team` if need to be updated. At first, I created a query like:

```
SELECT update_at FROM team WHERE id = 67
```

and then I compare `update_at` with 7 (which is the max number of days between an update and another).

This solution is expensive, because if I have 50 `teams` I need to open 50 connections and execute 50 `query`.

So I though to something like that:

```
SELECT id FROM `team` WHERE (id = 67 AND update_at > DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), Interval 7 Day)) 
                      AND id = 68 AND update_at > DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), Interval 7 Day))
```

The first problem here is the redundancy, I'm not a `sql` expert, so I don't know if is possible avoid to add each time `DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), Interval 7 Day)`.

The second problem is that the query doesn't return anything.

The table structure is the following:

```
id | name     | update_at
67   Tirana     2019-03-06 11:00:12  
68   Partizan   2019-03-06 11:02:04  
69   Lusitanos  2019-03-14 09:00:40
```

The expected result is `67, 68` because the `update_at` is less than 7 days from the current date. The record 69 was update only 2 days ago from today (2019-03-16).

UPDATE:

the duplicate doesn't fit all the question requirements. Because I need to return the id of each record that have an update_at field less than 7 days from the current date, not compare all the field as the other question –

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL query / dates older than 1 week ago (all datetimes in UTC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600481/mysql-query-dates-older-than-1-week-ago-all-datetimes-in-utc)

Comment: @DhruvMurarka the duplicate doesn't fit all the question requirements. Because I need to return the id of each record that have an `update_at` field less than 7 days from the current date, not  compare all the field as the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you don't want to know which IDs in the table lack a recent update. It is rather that you have a set of IDs you want to get this information for.

This would simply be:

```
SELECT id
FROM team
WHERE update_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND id IN (10, 22, 34, 56 ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

just check update_at> before 7 days and mysql doest have sysdate so you use `CURDATE()`

```
SELECT id FROM `team` WHERE update_at <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), Interval 7 Day)`
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, just some questions: 1. I need to check update_at for single record, and return the record id that need to be updated, why you didn't added the id 67, 68, 69 in your query? 2. If the id doesn't exists in the database the ouput will be null?

Comment: @sfarzoso: Somehow you think you must tell the DBMS which IDs to check. But no. You want the DBMS to tell *you* the IDs. So you tell the DBMS: "give me all IDs that haven't been updated in the last seven days". This is what the query does. You run the query once and it returns you *all* IDs that lack and update.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So basically if I have thousands of records, does the query return them all? This simply can't work for me

Comment: @sfarzoso: Why not? Let's say you have 10,000 rows in the table. 800 of them lack a recent update. The query returns these 800 IDs and in your app you can loop through them and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Because I have to compare the id from the application to the database, not vice versa. Is so complicated the query that I'm looking for?

Comment: @sfarzoso: *The* ID from the application? So there is only *one* ID to check? Why then doesn't your first query suffice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190140/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-thorsten-kettner).